# Debug hardhat solidity tests In WebStorm

Tags: debugging, webstorm, solidity, hardhat

After running Hardhat tests in the console with `npx hardhat test` I decided that being able to set break points would help me iterate faster.

How can I get Webstorm to run the underlying functions started by `npx hardhat test` so that I can use the built in Debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've since discovered that hardhat runs mocha under the hood.

To debug in WebStorm you can:

1. delete your existing configurations
2. create a new mocha configuration
3. set any configurations in 'Node options'. Note: since I'm forking the main net it takes a while for tests to start so I added the `--timeout 10000` because mocha's default timeout is only `2000ms`
4. select the mocha package, WebStorm doesn't select it by default
5. set your test file pattern
6. add `const {ethers} = require('hardhat');` to your test file because it is no longer injected by hardhat during run time.
7. If the green debug icon does not appear I had success in closing and reopening WebStorm.

At this point I could successfully set break points in my test file but not in the MyContract.sol file.  This is not surprising given that the contract is compiled before its run.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not able to run a single test from the arrow in the `*.test.ts` file with this configuration, do you?

Answer (score 4):

1. Create or open the `package.json` file for your Hardhat project.
2. Add a `test` NPM run script and save the file. Your package.json should look something like this.

```json
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "hardhat test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "2.0.2",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "2.0.1",
    "chai": "4.3.4",
    "ethereum-waffle": "3.4.0",
    "ethers": "5.4.4",
    "hardhat": "2.6.0"
  }
}
```

3. In the left gutter of the editor pane, a little play icon should appear, click it and then click `Debug "test"`.

I go through the instructions in a little more detail here, but this is the general idea. https://allendefibank.medium.com/how-to-debug-solidity-contracts-in-webstorm-hardhat-2ea0d3c4d582

Answer (score 1):

If you're use typescript you need to import **[ts-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha)** instead of *mocha*

Comment: This solution really saved my day! I think it's probably because of the configuration, causing *mocha* by default won't support .ts scripts. By switching to ts-mocha, the debug succeeded immediately. Thank you @Fedy_

Answer (score 1):

Install [ts-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha) as mentioned by @Fedy_

```
# remember to install mocha if you don't have it already (npm i -D mocha)

npm i -D ts-mocha

# install recent Mocha and Expect @types packages for best DX
npm i -D @types/mocha @types/expect
```

Add ts-mocha path to run Run/Debug configurations of IntelliJ IDEA

[image]